# SSRS Report Builder Aging Buckets

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder

I'm trying to create an aging report for customers by sales person. I have customer groups, then all the customers in that group. I'm trying to calculate the sum of money due by aging buckets of <30, Between 31 and 60, between 61 and 90, and >90.

My SQL view calculates the age of the bill in the table as **OverDueDays**, and the total of the bill as **AmountDC**.

I came up with the following for the <30 bucket, but it's not displaying the correct values.

```
=IIF(Fields!OverDueDays.Value<30 , Sum(Fields!AmountDC.Value),0)
```

Any ideas as to what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Reporting Services in a while, so the syntax may not be 100% correct.  Basically, you want to switch the order of your SUM and IIF.  Try something like:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!OverDueDays.Value < 30, Fields!AmountDC.Value, 0))
```

bonus: if you wanted to count the number of customers in a bucket:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!OverDueDays.Value < 30, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to do between, say 30 and 60? I don't see a between comparison function in ssrs report builder.

Answer (score 0):

try the following expressions if you have multiple datasets:

```
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), Now())<=0, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=1 and DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"),Now())<=30, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=31 and DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"),Now())<=60, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=61 and DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"),Now())<=90, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
=IIF(DateDiff("d", First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "Invoice"), now())>=91, RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, Sum, "Invoice"), 0)
```